# How to handle pie chart colors in jsf (Primrface)?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to change the colors of pie chart. Am using `primeface` it takes some colors as default how can i customize that colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `seriesColors` attribute.

Eg: `seriesColors: 66cc66, 93b75f`.

More info, see prime user guide, page 83

Comment: Note, i was using 3.5. They launch a new version.